# Return a list of Google Maps locations that I have previously specified

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-places-api

Let me begin by saying, I have been searching for resources for this question for more than 3 days, so I truly hope I did not miss an "answer" anywhere.

#### Background:

I am working on a website/app built in HTML/CSS/Javascript that will use geolocation **(Google Maps & Places API)** to find a users location and return them the (for example) top 5 closest water parks to them at that location they are currently at.

#### Question:

I want to control the list of results the API picks from. So let's say, it'll only give them 5 out of 30 water parks that are near them and I have previously specified the names/locations of those 30 water parks.

The reason I want to do this is because after searching via Google Maps for "water parks nearby 123 Main Street, City, State" - it doesn't return *all* the results I want it to, just some.

As I stated, I have looked far and wide for this answer. I have read almost all of the relevant Google Places API and Maps API documentation with no clear cut answer. I have also found a few website that let you use a Google Docs spreadsheet to specify locations, but you can't get the code from them. And I have seen a few example using XML, but nothing exactly what I'm looking for.

I will also note that I am familiar with C# and PHP if that helps get me closer to my goal. But it seems like Javascript is the way to go.

Any help/hints/tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data in a database that supports spatial queries(may be a FusionTable for example), then you may use `ST_DISTANCE` to order the results by distance and `LIMIT` to limit the resultset.

Comment: This seems like a very good solution. I've never used Fusion Tables, but after reading the documentation they seem to allow what I am looking for.

Has anyone had experience combining Fusion Tables and Maps API.

Comment: When you want to  use the returned data  without a map, simply send a request via AJAX(JSONP is supported), there is no special support for  querying the data with the Maps-API(except you want to show the results on a map via a FusionTableLayer )